# How to define fixed variables in Anchor programs

Tags: anchor, solana-program, anchor-lang

Is it possible to define a variable within the `Anchor.toml` file and then use it during run time inside the anchor program? I couldn't find how in the docs.

I guess an alternative could be defining the variables within a `Cargo.toml` file, but I would like to know the "anchor approach" to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i Think that you need to use both TOML and serde crates like in this example:
https://codingpackets.com/blog/rust-load-a-toml-file/

Another alternative would be using a .env file:
https://nunomaduro.com/load_environment_variables_from_dotenv_files_in_your_rust_program